# Webpage background image not being displayed

Tags: asp.net, html, css

I've downloaded a background image for my website, and for some reason or other, it's simply not being displayed.

This is the CSS code I've got:

```
background-image: url(Resources/Icons/background-image.jpg);
background-attachment: fixed;
```

I've even tried adding the full path name - to no avail.

The strange thing is that I've done this numerous times in my website, and all my images are displayed. It's only this that's giving me a problem - and there is no red cross showing that it cannot find the image - it just doesn't appear.

EDIT: For some reason, if I place the url of the webage where I got the image from, it works.

Any ideas?

Comment: What do you see in Firebug's Net tab?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is your css in the same directory as your image?  Probably not, I would assume.  So you need to get back to the root and access the image properly.

Something like:

```
background-image: url(../Resources/Icons/background-image.jpg)
```

Comment: This was my problem! Thanks so much :) Do you think you could explain why this was required? As I said, I've used this method for many images which are all placed in the 'Icons' directory, and I did not have this problem.

Comment: I can't answer for sure - but it depends on how your folders are laid out.

Answer (score 1):

Unless your stylesheet resides in the same folder as you images, you should try navigating from the root:

```
background-image("/images/someimage.png");
```

Personally, I've found that navigating from the root of the application/site tends to be the most reliable/scalable option.

Comment: Thanks. The thing is that I've done this numerous times for other images, and they've all worked except for this one. Any idea why?

Comment: Is this CSS on your page or in a stylesheet? If it's on the page, could it have soemthing to do with where the page lives, perhaps?

Comment: Everything's on a stylesheet. Strange. Thanks for the assistance!

Comment: That is strange. Glad you got it fixed though :)

Answer (score -1):

Wrong path probably...

```
background-image: url('/Resources/Icons/background-image.jpg');
```